# Difference between lists in Python

Tags: python, list

Is there any way to detect distinction after two lists comparison, if second list is more important?

```
List1 items: 1 2 3 4
List2 items: 1 2   4
```

Expected result should be: `remove 3`

```
List1 items: 1 2 3 4 
List2 items: 1 2 3 4 5
```

Expected result should be: `no further changes`

```
List1 items: 1 2 3 4 5
List2 items: 1 2 3 4 6
```

Expected result should be: `remove 5`

Comment: Have you actually *tried* anything?

Comment: Sure, I tried intersect and something like: [x for x in platform_normal_array if x not in s]

Comment: Please edit the question to give a [mcve].

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html

Comment: Why aren't additions considered a change?

Comment: Also, what should be the result if the order of items is different between the lists? This question is not clearly specified yet.

Comment: order of items is not important in my case. I just want to remove items from 1st list, which are not present in 2nd list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I just want to remove items from 1st list, which are not present in 2nd list"

"Expected result should be: remove 3"

```
In [11]: list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}
In [12]: list2 = {1, 2, 4}
In [13]: set.difference(list1, list2)
Out[13]: {3}
```

"Expected result should be: no further changes"

```
In [14]: list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}
In [15]: list2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
In [16]: set.difference(list1, list2)
Out[16]: set()
```

"Expected result should be: remove 5"

```
In [17]: list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
In [18]: list2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6}
In [19]: set.difference(list1, list2)
Out[19]: {5}
```

Answer (score 1):

`set(list1) - set(list2)` will return a set of missing items.